# Wordpress Multi Step Survey

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I'm new to web development and I've been working with this for quite a while now. I'm using wordpress and I need help on doing a multi step survey on wordpress like this one.
[sample](http://allfinanz.com.au/offers/60-sec-quiz/)

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugins, I do a search but not find out any multiple steps form jQuery for WordPress.

Here is Contact form 7 Multiple step plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/

And here is the demo: http://webheadcoder.com/contact-form-7-multi-step-form/
It's not jQuery multiple steps form for a fast transfer movement, but you can use it for your survey purpose.

Contact form 7 itself does not save submitted data to database, but you can find an extension to do it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/
This is to help you get the survey data from use and analyze it.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, This will help a lot :)

Comment: Also, you can use Gravity Form plugin, It has progress bar:
http://www.gravityforms.com/features/form-builder/

I think that's what you need.